# Select2 en django no me muestra las opciones a seleccionar

Tags: django, select, select2

```
    Estoy intentando hacer un select múltiple donde al elegir una comunidad, se muestren sólo las provincias de esa comunidad y no las de otras comunidades.
```

Este es mi código:

En forms.py:

```
    '''from django import forms
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from .models import Comunidad, Pais, Provincia
    from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget



    class AddressForm(forms.Form):
         comunidad = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Comunidad.objects.all(),
    label=u"Comunidad",
    widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
        dependent_fields={'provincia': 'provincia'},
        search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        
    )
)

      provincia = forms.ModelChoiceField(
         queryset=Provincia.objects.all(),
         label=u"Provincia",
         widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
        
          search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        
            max_results=500,
         )
        )'''
```

En models.py tengo esto:

```
    '''class Comunidad (models.Model):
name= models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Añada Comunidad Autónoma")
pais = models.ForeignKey('Pais', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='comunidades')

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Comunidades"


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

    class Provincia(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Añada provincia")
        comunidad = models. ForeignKey('Comunidad', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    '''
```

y en el template:

```
    '''{{form.as_table}}'''
```

El resultado que obtengo son los botones con el texto "comunidad" y " "provincia" y junto a cada uno de ellos un botón para desplegar un menú, pero aparce vacío, no me carga las comunidades ni provincias que tengo en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé qué me estoy saltando, pero está claro que algo me falta, si alguien me pudiera ayudar, sería genial. Necesito que se cargen las diferentes comunidades y provincias de la base de datos para seguir avanzando. ¿Qué puedo hacer?